# Why :redraw! not take effect in augroup?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, redraw, vim-airline

I use Vim-Airline plug in Vim, but statuline incomplete display after source .vimrc, so I want use :redraw! in augroup but it not take effect.

```
augroup Vim
autocmd!
autocmd BufWritePost $MYVIMRC ++nested source $MYVIMRC ":redraw!"
augroup End
```

I can only exec :redraw! in command line.
How to improve my code?

Comment: Why exactly do you expect that to do anything?

Comment: @romainl, I wanna do redraw automatic after source .vimrc.

Comment: What you want to do is clear. Why you think that code can do it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure where those quotes around `:redraw!` come from or what you expect them to do since `"` introduces a comment.

In Vim, you use a "bar", `|`, to separate Ex commands like `:source` and `:redraw`:

```
augroup Vim
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePost $MYVIMRC ++nested source $MYVIMRC | redraw!
augroup END
```

See `:help :bar`.